# Impact of large dataset on the trained model size?

Tags: deep-learning, dataset, large-data

If the dataset is large does it mean that the model size will also be large?

Answer (score 0):

for example our real world data is function `y = ax + b`

> dataset is all data point on this line
>
> model is our mathematical representation for representing these data
>
> model size is number of parameter we use for representation

now the model size is related to a real world function we want to representing.

we can create a huge dataset for line `ax + b` but the model of this function only need two parameters `a` and `b` and if we have only two point of this line we can create model

real world data are not simple as a line but if we have some model with same result model with least number of parameter is beast one.

**The training dataset size depends on the complexity of our model**

Comment: Thanks for response. For example, let's say i have 2 dataset of image one containing 1000 48*48 pixels grayscale image, and the other one containing 500. Now if i train a neural network with only one hidden layer, will the resultant models vary in size? @amin saffar